# Python: How to raise an exception when keyword does not match up?

Tags: python

When comparing strings I want to raise an exception when they do not equal:

```
x = 'obama'
if x == 'obama' or 'bush' or 'kennedy' :
    pass
else:
    raise exception
```

Comment: sytax error, refer to the answer below by "code frenzy".

Answer (score 3):

check `x` 3 times like so:

```
x = 'obama'
if x == 'obama' or x == 'bush' or x == 'kennedy' :
    pass
else:
    raise exception
```

you can also use the `in` keyword for the check like so:

```
x = 'obama'
if x in ['obama', 'bush', 'kennedy']:
    pass
else:
    raise exception
```